# Initialize a controller inside a template that is loaded via directive?

Tags: angularjs

Get response

```
<section ng-controller="BookingController"></section>
```

Directive

```
MyApp.directive "loadThing", ($rootScope, $compile) ->
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
            $.get BASE_URL + '/load/template/' + attrs.loadThing, (response) ->
                element.html(response)
                $compile(element)
    }
```

I'm loading a template with ajax that has an ng-controller declared in it, but the controller is not being initialized.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, was a silly mistake.

Needed to be:

```
template = $(response)
$compile(template)(scope)
element.append(template)
```

Key flaw was not calling the function $compile returns.

Answer (score 0):

Link is generally used for event based behavior, I'm not sure why you're using Ajax but you might try declaring your controller and template in the controller. It would look something like this:

```
MyApp.directive('loadThing', function($rootScope, $compile) {
    return {
         restrict: "AE",
         templateUrl: 'yourPathHere.js',
         controller: 'MyController'
    }
});
```